# store is not defined react-redux

Tags: react-redux

I'm new to React trying to build a random quotes generator,
the console error says store is not defined when using 
this is my redux code:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import axios from 'axios';

const quotesList = array of objects each quote has text and author

const CHANGE_QUOTE = "CHANGE_QUOTE";

const changeQuote = () => {
    return {
        type: CHANGE_QUOTE
    }
}

const quoteReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_QUOTE: return quotesList[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesList.length)];
        default: return state;
    }
}

const store = createStore(quoteReducer);

store.dispatch(changeQuote());
console.log(store.getState());
```

and in the react code i am importing the provider and connect from react-redux

```
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      quote: state
    }
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      getNewQuote: () => {
        dispatch(changeQuote());
      }
    }
  };
const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Quote);

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Container />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export your quotereducer and then import in app.js and do this

```
import {quoteReducer} from '../your path';
const store = createStore(quoteReducer);


class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Container />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thank you, it worked for my case,
but what if I have a file for each component I will need the store to be in the redux file

Comment: you only place the store and provider tag in top root comopnent. So thats how it hsould be done , and if it helped you. do mark the answer as accepted